# Single-threaded program profiles 15% of runtime in semaphore_wait_trap

Tags: f#, mono, profiling

On Mac OS using mono, if I compile and profile the program below, I get the following results:

```
% fsharpc --nologo -g foo.fs -o foo.exe
% mono --profile=default:stat foo.exe
...
Statistical samples summary
    Sample type: cycles
    Unmanaged hits:     336 (49.1%)
    Managed hits:       349 (50.9%)
    Unresolved hits:      1 ( 0.1%)
  Hits      % Method name
   154  22.48 Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SetTreeModule:height ...
   105  15.33 semaphore_wait_trap
    74  10.80 Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SetTreeModule:add ...
...
```

Note the second entry, `semaphore_wait_trap`. 
Here is the program:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    let s = seq { 1..1000000 } |> Set.ofSeq
    s |> Seq.iter (fun _ -> ())
    0
```

I looked in the [source for the Set module](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/set.fs), but I didn't find any (obvious) locking.

Is my single-threaded program really spending 15% of its execution time messing with semaphores? If it is, can I make it not do that and get a performance boost?

Comment: Is debugging enabled?

Comment: I've tried both ways, and I get `semaphore_wait_trap` in the top-3 either way.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't in the allocator and/or GC?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. Mono's GC is stop-the-world, and so probably shouldn't need locking (right?). And from [this](http://www.mono-project.com/Generational_GC#Allocation) it seems allocation requires only the occasional compare-and-swap, which should always succeed in a single-threaded case like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Instruments, it's sgen/gc calling semaphore_wait_trap:

[image]

[Sgen is documented](http://www.mono-project.com/Generational_GC) as stopping all other threads while it collects:

> Before doing a collection (minor or major), the collector must stop
>   all running threads so that it can have a stable view of the current
>   state of the heap, without the other threads changing it

In other words, when the code is trying to allocate memory and a GC is required, the time it takes shows up under semaphore_wait_trap since that's your application thread.  I suspect the mono profiler doesn't profile the gc thread itself so you don't see the time in the collection code.

The germane output then is really the GC summary:

```
GC summary
    GC resizes: 0
    Max heap size: 0
    Object moves: 1002691
    Gen0 collections: 123, max time: 14187us, total time: 354803us, average: 2884us
    Gen1 collections: 3, max time: 41336us, total time: 60281us, average: 20093us
```

If you want your code to run faster, don't collect as often.

Understanding the actual cost of collection can be done through dtrace since [sgen has dtrace probes](http://www.mono-project.com/SGen_DTrace).